# Difference between vacuolar and symplast pathway

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

what is the difference between **Vacuolar  Pathway** and **Symplast Pathway** ? Is the symplast pathway does not take into account the vacuole to vacuole movement?

Answer (score 1):

The vacuolar pathway involves the movement of water between vacuoles of neighbouring plant cells. The symplast pathway, on the other hand, involves the movement of water from the cytoplasm of one cell to the cytoplasm of a neighbouring plant cell without it entering a vacuole inbetween, so the symplast pathway has no vacuole to vacuole movement.

[image]